# Systematic sampling in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, sampling

I’m quite new to PySpark and I’ve been struggling to find the answer I’m looking for.

I have a large sample of households and I want to conduct systematic sampling. Like true systematic sampling, I would like to begin at a random starting point and then select a household at regular intervals (e.g. every 50th household). I have looked into sample() and sampleBy(), but I don't think these are quite what I need. Can anyone give any advice on how I can do this? Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`monotonically_increasing_id` works if you have only 1 partition, so if you have more than just 1 partition, you can consider `row_number`.

Check "Notes" in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id.html

With `row_number`,

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn("index", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('somecol')))
     .filter(((F.col('index') + random_start) % 50) == 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for saving me quite some time in trying to figure this out! This was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) then modulo by 50 to get what you want.

Comment: Thank you - that's so helpful! Do you know whether this allows for a random starting point?

Comment: You can sort the dataframe randomly then apply `monotonically_increasing_id`